# Perl: How to list ids from multiple HTML?

Tags: regex, list, perl

I have multiple HTML files in a subfolder. Each HTML page have the multiple page ids like this `<a id="page_1"/>`, `<a id="page_2"/>`, `<a id="page_3"/>`, et cetera. I wish to list page ids which is in which HTML page like `page_3:index.html`, `page_4:chapter.html`, `page_5:content.html`

How can I do that?

Comment: In HTML the end tag for `<a>` elements is mandatory. You cannot use XML-style self-closing tag syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Some people think that the easiest way involves a regex:

```
use v5.22;
while( <<>> ) {
    next unless /<a id="(.*?)"/;
    say "$ARGV: $1";
    }
```

That might get you the answer quickly in a dirty way. That could be acceptable for a quick one-off task. I'm using the [extra-safe double diamond that v5.22 added](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/05/use-perl-5-22s-operator-for-safe-command-line-handling/).

If you need something more robust, such as [Mojo::DOM](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM):

```
use v5.22;
use Mojo::DOM;

foreach my $file ( @ARGV ) {
    my $data = do { local( @ARGV, $/ ) = $file; <<>> };
    my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $data );
    my @ids = $dom->find( 'a[id]' )->map( attr => 'id' )->each;
    say "$ARGV: @ids";
    }
```